# $A$ not equal to $0$ and $B$ not equal to $0$ but $AB=0$

Tags: matrices

Give the example of matrix $A$ and $B$ s.t. $A$ not equal to $0$ and $B$ not equal to $0$ but $AB=0$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide more context: what do you find difficult here? What do you already know?

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Find a non-zero $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2=0$.

Solution:

> If $A$ is a strictly upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix, then $A^n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ and $B=A$

Comment: better not to say the answer directly. you and lhf has given the same answer. but there is a obvious difference.

Comment: True that is what I upvote his ;)

Answer (score 0):

Of course  I can give a example $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1\\  0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ $B =  \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ so $AB = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$. Hope it helps you.